# Set up basic Batch or Node.JS prompts for FFMPEG?

Tags: node.js, batch-file, ffmpeg

I have some game clips from Nvidia shadow play that I like to casually shorten and / or turn them into webms or keep them as mp4s. I use the same ffmpeg line for them. I do slightly change the line because of the input file, start time, and output file.

How could I set up something like a batch file (I was thinking maybe node as well) where it just asks for the input file, start time, and output file?

The current ffmpeg command line I use is like this: 
`ffmpeg -i desktop.mp4 -ss 00:01:50 -b 900000 -vf scale=640:trunc(ow/a/2)*2 output.webm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prompt for user input using the following pattern:

```
SET /P FILENAME=Enter Filename:
ECHO USER ENTERED %FILENAME%
```

So with your code you'd setup your 3 variables then use:

```
ffmpeg -i "%INFILE%" -ss %STARTTIME% -b 900000 -vf scale=640:trunc(ow/a/2)*2 "%OUTFILE%"
```